# style.css not working while using flask python

Tags: python, html, css, json, flask

When I try to run my app.py which starts a local url to run my html file the style.css does not work. It was working before i connected my script.js to it. clearing cache does not seem to work

my files director location is like this:

```
app.py(flask)
templates
--index.html
static
--script.js
--style.css
```

my html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <title>Interactive Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" id="user-input" placeholder="Enter your input...">
        <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-box" id="chat-box">
        <!-- Chat messages will be displayed here -->
    </div>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my app.py code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from Bot import chat_bot#this is where I am getting the output to display on the site
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/process_input", methods=["POST"])
def process_input():
    data = request.get_json()
    user_input = data["input"]

    # Process the input (replace with your actual processing logic)
    processed_result = chat_bot("AI",user_input)

    return jsonify({"response": processed_result})

def process_data(input_data):
    # Replace this with your actual processing logic
    processed_result = f"You entered: {input_data}"
    return processed_result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.config["SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT"] = 0
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

I was expecting for the code to have styles. If more details are needed, please inform me as I am willing to give them.

Comment: In the webserver log, do you see the browser actually making a request for `style.css`?  And if so, was that request successful?

Comment: i can see the file in sources however it does not seem to work in the actual site @JohnGordon

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  What is in **the actual webserver log**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works on my machine.

[image: Works on my machine.]

You didn't post your CSS nor JS so I went with a sample button resize and alert when the button is clicked, and everything works. Validate your CSS and JS, see if it's fine and then try to update/reinstall Flask.

It could also be the `from Bot import chatbot` as that wasn't posted as well. Make sure you're not overriding any CSS from there.